# Find matrix P for quadratic transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Choose the matrix $P$ below such that if we make the change of variables $\vec x = P \vec y$, then the quadratic form $Q(\vec x) = 3x_1^2 - 4\sqrt 2 x_1x_2 + 5x_2^2$ transforms into a quadratic form $Q(\vec y)$ with no cross-product term.

I solved this question and I got the answer of $\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{3} & -\sqrt{3}/3 \\ 1/\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix}$, but the answer choices are

a. $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\sqrt{2} \\ -2\sqrt{2} &1 \end{bmatrix}$

b. $P = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 2 & \sqrt{2} \\ -2 &1 \end{bmatrix}$

c. $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 &1 \end{bmatrix}$

d. $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\sqrt{3} \\ \sqrt{3} &1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: there are infinitely many matrices $P$ that work: let $Q$ be the Hessian matrix of the quadratic form, you are asked for $P^T Q P = D.$ You could just calculate the four such products

Comment: I haven't learned what Hessian Matrices are yet.

Comment: let us  take half the Hessian matrix, call it $H$ $$  H = \left( \begin{array}{rr} 3 & -2 \sqrt 2 \\ -2 \sqrt 2 & 5  \end{array}\right) .$$ Now calculate $P^THP$ for each

Comment: Then what do I do?

Comment: if $P^THP$ is diagonal, that is an answer. Given the wording, it is not clear whether they are allowing more than one correct answer.

Comment: Hace you ever heard something abour how to diagonalize quadratic forms by linear transformations (rows & columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by the ratios of the eigen vector components.

$$H = \left( \begin{array}{rr} 3 & -2 \sqrt 2 \\ -2 \sqrt 2 & 5  \end{array}\right) \tag{1}$$

$$(H-\lambda I)v = 0\tag{2}$$

$$ \det \left( \begin{array}{rr} 3 - \lambda& -2 \sqrt 2 \\ -2 \sqrt 2 & 5 - \lambda \end{array}\right) = 0 \tag{3}$$

$$ (3 - \lambda)(5-\lambda) - 8 = 0 \tag{4}$$

$$ {\lambda}^2 - 8 \lambda  + 7 = 0 \tag{5}$$

$$ ({\lambda} - 1)(\lambda  - 7) = 0 \tag{6}$$

The eigen values are:
$${\lambda}_1 = 1 \:,\: {\lambda}_2=7$$

---

Now find the eigen vectors for ${\lambda}_1$ see $(2)$

$$\left( \begin{array}{rr} 3-1 & -2 \sqrt 2 \\ -2 \sqrt 2 & 5-1  \end{array}\right) 
\left( \begin{array}{rr} v_{11} \\ v_{12}  \end{array}\right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{rr} 2 & -2 \sqrt 2 \\ -2 \sqrt 2 & 4  \end{array}\right) 
\left( \begin{array}{rr} v_{11} \\ v_{12}  \end{array}\right) = 0\tag{7}$$

This gives:

$$ 2 v_{11} -2 \sqrt{2} v_{12} = 0 \tag{8}$$

$$ \frac{v_{11}}{v_{12}} = \sqrt{2}  \tag{9}$$

**Note that the relationship is a ratio so it can have many scalar solutions.**

---

Now find the eigen vectors for ${\lambda}_2$ see $(2)$

$$\left( \begin{array}{rr} 3-7 & -2 \sqrt 2 \\ -2 \sqrt 2 & 5-7  \end{array}\right) 
\left( \begin{array}{rr} v_{21} \\ v_{22}  \end{array}\right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{rr} -4 & -2 \sqrt 2 \\ -2 \sqrt 2 & -2  \end{array}\right) 
\left( \begin{array}{rr} v_{21} \\ v_{22}  \end{array}\right) = 0\tag{8}$$

This gives:

$$ -4 v_{21} -2 \sqrt{2} v_{22} = 0 \tag{9}$$

$$ \frac{v_{21}}{v_{22}} = -\frac1{\sqrt{2}}  \tag{10}$$

---

The order of the eigen values in the diagonal matrix is arbitrary but the order of eigen values and their vectors must be the same.

So you are looking for $P$ with top and bottom eigen vector ratios in each column of:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{rr} \sqrt{2} & 1  \\ 1 & -\sqrt{2} \end{array}\right) or 
\left( \begin{array}{rr}  1 & \sqrt{2}   \\ -\sqrt{2} & 1  \end{array}\right) \tag{11}$$

---

$$b.P = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 2 & \sqrt{2} \\ -2 &1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Has this ratio.

---

Sanity check.
Octave:

```
 H = [3 -2*sqrt(2);-2*sqrt(2),5];
 P = [sqrt(2),sqrt(2); -2,1]
 P^-1*H*P
 ans =

   7.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   1.00000
```

This gives the correct eigen values in the diagonal matrix.

---

$$D = P^{-1}HP \tag{12}$$

$$ PDP^{-1} = H \tag{13}$$

$$ PDP^{-1}x = Hx \tag{14}$$

$$ P^{-1}x = y \tag{15}$$

$$ x = Py \tag{16}$$

---

Your answer is a correct solution. Factoring out $\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$ and swapping the order of the eigen vectors matches the ratios within the columns of $b$.

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{3} & -\sqrt{3}/3 \\ 1/\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix} =
 \frac1{\sqrt{3}} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & -1 \\ 1 & \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} 
\xrightarrow[{\text{columns}}]{\text{swap}}
\begin{bmatrix}   -1 & \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2} & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow[{\text{times}\: -\sqrt{2}}]{1_{}st \:\text{column}}
\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 2 & \sqrt{2} \\ -2 &1 \end{bmatrix}
$$